# Why are cyclic groups of order $p$ (prime) unique up to isomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

It says [here](http://www2.lawrence.edu/fast/corrys/Math300/8Groups.pdf) that "By the classification of cyclic groups, there is only one group of each order[prime] (up to isomorphism)".

What is the intuition behind this and how would you go about proving this? An proof would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n\in \Bbb N$ and $A,B$ two finite cyclic groups, both of order $n$ (not necessarily prime).
Then by definition of "cyclic" $A=\langle a\rangle$, $B=\langle b\rangle$ for some generartors $a,b$. Verify that $a^k\mapsto b^k$ defines a homomorphism $A\to B$ that is in fact an isomorphism.

Upon deeper reading, the statement made in the linked text is *intended* to mean something else (and relies on a different proof than the classification of cyclic groups!):

> If $p$ is prime and $G$ a group of order $p$, then $G$ is cyclic.

This follows from [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_%28group_theory%29) because for any $g\in G$ with $g\ne 1$, the group $\langle g\rangle$ must have order $>1$ and dividing $p$, hence $G=\langle g\rangle$ is cyclic.

Comment: How does $a^k\mapsto b^k$ define a homomorphism?

Comment: @JammieDodger The general element of $A$ has the form $a^k$ and $b^k$ is an element of $B$. So how does it *not* define a homomorphism?

Comment: @JammieDodger Do you really understand how the group operation goes? Just extend that to all of $A$ by just varying $k$.

Comment: Sorry I get that now. But why is this homomorphism a bijection?

Comment: @JammieDodger because $b^k\mapsto a^k$ is an inverse homomorphism of it.

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is cyclic with generator $g$, there is a unique surjective homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to G$ sending $1$ to $g$.  By the First Isomorphism Theorem and the classification of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$, $G\cong \mathbb{Z}/n$ for some $n$.