# Any good ways to prove that there is only one group of order 2?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

When you take a course like Abstract Algebra, the professors just "let it be given" that there is only one group of order $2, \mathbb{Z_2}$. But they don't go about proving this, despite proving nearly everything else. How do we come to assert that, for example, there is only one group of order $2$ $(\mathbb{Z_2})$ and only one group of order $3$ $(\mathbb{Z_3})$? Is there a proof of it somewhere? I'm not finding anything on the internet.

I suspect a proof by contradication would be helpful here, constructing a group with arbitrary values.

Comment: Take a group $G$ of order 2, construct its table, and use that to define an isomorphism with $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: The only product that follows not immediately from the definition of the neutral element $e$ is $a^2$ , that the map $g->ag$ is injective easily implies $a^2=e$ and the uniqueness upto isomorphism is proven.

Comment: " I'm not finding anything on the internet."  This is strange. This site has many posts with a proof that there is only one group of order $p$, with $p$ prime. See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1690158/why-are-cyclic-groups-of-order-p-prime-unique-up-to-isomorphism).